# Having trouble passing variable from php to bash

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm trying to set up an html form that passes variables to a php script, that then passes them to a bash script.

I'm able to successfully pass variables from the html form to the php script, and I'm able to make the following pass variables to my bash script:

```
<?php
shell_exec('./bashscript.sh testarg1 testarg2 testarg3 testarg4');
?>
```

But, when I use the following:

```
<?php
  shell_exec('./bashscript.sh $_POST[arg1] $_POST[arg2] $_POST[arg3] $_POST[arg4]');
?>
```

I end up with:

```
[arg1]
[arg2]
[arg3]
[arg4]
```

This is the first time I've tried passing from php to bash.  The bracketed arguments post to a db with no prob.  How would I change this to successfully pass the arguments to my bash script? thx.

Comment: Properly concatenate! `'./bashscript.sh '.$_POST['arg1'].' '.$_POST['arg2'].'...'` e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double-quoted string, not inside single-quoted strings.

```
shell_exec("./bashscript.sh $_POST[arg1] $_POST[arg2] $_POST[arg3] $_POST[arg4]");
```

This is basic PHP syntax, having nothing to do with using the shell.

You should also use `escape_shell_arg` to escape each argument before substituting it, in case it contains shell metacharacters.